# problem with Views module (installation)

Tags: views, 7, commerce

I had a `views` page created on my site and it seemed to work well. Then I started to update some of the modules that updates wre available for and then all of a sudden, my `views` module didn't seem to be installed anymore. So what I did, went back to reinstall it, now the link to my views page on the site is back (http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/special-events) but when I click on it, I get this error: `Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/content/q/u/a/quaa7882/html/sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/includes/view.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/q/u/a/quaa7882/html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3047` 
`commerce_kickstart` is a module I have removed in the meantime and am no using it anymore nor is it in my modules `directory`. Why is something still referring to it? How can I fix this?

Thank you,
Ron

Comment: Very importantly, _how_ did you update/reinstall Views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views module was installed as a part of commerce_kickstart in sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib. You removed that distribution, which is a good idea because it was installed in the wrong directory (should be in /profiles). 
Most probably you then downloaded and reinstalled a fresh views in sites/all/modules.

If you move a module you should clear the cache or (in some cases) rebuild the registry.

The easiest way to clear the cache when you cannot reach the admin of the site is to go to /update.php and run the update process (take a backup first).
Other options are the [Registry Rebuild module](https://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) or Drush (drush cc all).

Comment: Great, running `update.php` did the trick! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

commerce_kickstart is not a module, is an install profile, and it shouldn't go in your modules directory nor be installed as a module.

If you've installed the site using the commerce kickstart profile and you've removed it, you might have more problems similar to this one, one thing you need to do to fix this is to set the profile back to standard:

```
UPDATE variable SET value = 'standard' WHERE name = 'install_profile';
TRUNCATE cache;
```

Check out: http://davehall.com.au/blog/dave/2012/09/12/switching-installation-profiles-existing-drupal-sites

Other things that you'll probably want to do is to make sure that commerce kickstart is not in the system table in database and clearing cache and [registry rebuild](https://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) are a couple of extra things that won't harm.